# Sumar ventas que llegaron a su meta por sucursales

Tags: sql-server, sql

Tengo una tabla de de metas por ventas, donde se actualiza constantemente la meta alcanzada, la tabla también tiene una regla a cumplir, es decir que la meta puede ser `'<'`, `'<='` y otras reglas. 
También tengo otra tabla llamada sucursales.
Lo que trato de obtener son los avances que llegaron a las metas mencionadas y la consulta todo ok, el problema es que necesito saber de las otras sedes y asignarles cero `(0)` a los que no llegaron a la meta.

> En la consulta actual obtengo lo siguiente:

```
select count(*) 'total', vm.sucursal_id 
from ventas_metas vm
LEFT JOIN sucursales su on su.sucursal_id = vm.sucursal_id
where vm.meta_ejecutado <= vm.meta_esperado
and (vm.regla = '>=' or vm.regla = '>') 
group by vm.sucursal_id;
```

[image: Resultado Query]

> Lo que intento obtener es lo siguiente:

[image: Resultado esperado]

> Tabla principal

[image: Tabla principal]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que la condición restringe que ingresen las demás sedes que no cumplen la condición, para solucionar ese tema podemos usar [CASE](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_case.asp) e incluir las condiciones dentro del COUNT.

```
select 
count(case when vm.meta_ejecutado <= vm.meta_esperado and (vm.regla = '>=' or vm.regla = '>') then 1 else null end) 'total', vm.sucursal_id 
from ventas_metas vm
LEFT JOIN sucursales su on su.sucursal_id = vm.sucursal_id
group by vm.sucursal_id;
```

Lo que hacemos básicamente es que al momento de contar comparamos los que cumplen las reglas de todos los registros, así tendremos el resultado esperado.

Comment: Es exactamente lo que buscaba!

Answer (score 1):

Dejo un par de alternativas que podrían reducir la cantidad de datos leídos. Me tomé la libertad de cambiar un poco la lógica para que estuviera de acuerdo a lo que indica la regla.

Lo primero que hice fue dejar ventas_metas como tabla secundaria y así dejar la lógica en el JOIN y contar solo las filas que cumplieran con la misma.

```
SELECT s.sucursal_id,
       COUNT(vm.sucursal_id) AS total
FROM sucursales s
LEFT JOIN ventas_metas vm ON s.sucursal_id = vm.sucursal_id
                          AND ((vm.meta_ejecutado <= vm.meta_esperado AND vm.regla = '>=') 
                              OR (vm.meta_ejecutado < vm.meta_esperado AND vm.regla = '>'))
GROUP BY s.sucursal_id;
```

Pero como a veces el motor de SQL Server requiere un poco de ayuda para optimizar la consulta, podemos dividir para aprovechar mejor los índices.

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT s.sucursal_id,
           COUNT(vm.sucursal_id) AS total
    FROM sucursales s
    LEFT JOIN ventas_metas vm ON s.sucursal_id = vm.sucursal_id
                              AND vm.meta_ejecutado <= vm.meta_esperado 
                              and vm.regla = '>='
    GROUP BY s.sucursal_id
    UNION ALL
    SELECT s.sucursal_id,
           COUNT(vm.sucursal_id) AS total
    FROM sucursales s
    LEFT JOIN ventas_metas vm ON s.sucursal_id = vm.sucursal_id
                              AND vm.meta_ejecutado < vm.meta_esperado 
                              AND vm.regla = '>'
    GROUP BY s.sucursal_id
)
SELECT sucursal_id,
       SUM(total) AS total
FROM CTE 
GROUP BY sucursal_id;
```

Ninguna de estas soluciones está garantizada para funcionar mejor, pero vale la pena probarlas para ver cual se ajusta mejor a tu entorno.